# Exponential Growth, Fit, Log of Curve

Tags: statistics, optimization, exponential-function, curves

I have data for three exponential curves, I computed log on the $y$ because

$$
y = a e ^{b x}
$$

$$
log(y) = log(a eb x) = log(a) + log(eb x) = log(a) + b x.
$$

Now from a perfect exponential growth we'd expect to see straight lines. But, for example the blue line, if I have changing slopes, can I interpret that as $b$ also depending on time? Or should I rule out the whole exponential curve as simply a "bad fit"?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you simply do not have exponential functions.

Comment: OK.. but, bear with me :), so after x=15, the blue line is straight, so say I took log of data on two regions seperately, before and after x=15,  wouldn't I have two seperate exponentials in a way, no?

Comment: In some way yes. If the curves are linear on some intervals then an exponential will be a good approximation to the curve in that region.

Answer (score 1):

Your blue curve indicates two regions where $b$ has two distinct values. This leads to different behavior when you have small or large $x$. I have found that in problems like this the following curve fit can be helpful.

$$\ln\frac ya=\frac{1}{\big(\frac{1}{b_1x}+\frac{1}{b_2x}\bigg)}$$